# pg gem upgraded 0.19 to 0.20 - LoadError: incompatible library version

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rvm, capistrano3, pg

I'm using Capistrano 3 to manage my deployments to AWS, developing on OS X and serving on Ubuntu.

I continue to run into the following issue whenever I upgrade my Gemfile and bundle:

```
  01 rake aborted!
  01 LoadError: incompatible library version - /var/www/<app_name>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/pg-0.20.0/lib/pg_ext.so
  01 /var/www/<app_name>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/pg-0.20.0/lib/pg.rb:4:in `require'
  01 /var/www/<app_name>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/pg-0.20.0/lib/pg.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
  01 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@global/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in `require'
  01 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@global/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in `block (2 levels) in require'
  01 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@global/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `each'
  01 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@global/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `block in require'
  01 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@global/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `each'
  01 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@global/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `require'
  01 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@global/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler.rb:107:in `require'
  01 /var/www/<app_name>/releases/20170406223132/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
  01 /var/www/<app_name>/releases/20170406223132/Rakefile:4:in `require'
  01 /var/www/<app_name>/releases/20170406223132/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
  01 /var/www/<app_name>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
  01 (See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I don't even know where to begin to troubleshoot this. Is this a problem with RVM? Is this a problem with bundler? My app?

I've tried the suggestions found on [this RVM issue](https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/3645) but to no avail. Suggestions please?

Also, if there's a way to manage this using Capistrano, that'd be preferable, as the purpose of Capistrano is remote system management. But if I *have* to log into the server, I will - I just don't see why I should have to.

**Update** - I've gone so far as to completely destroy the RVM gemset and get it to try to fully "reinstall" all gems - still results in the same error as below.

Comment: I'd say it's a problem with PostgreSQL version on your target machine. Which is that?

Comment: @katafrakt - winner winner - that was it. I had the 9.5 server with a 9.6 client.

Comment: Bonus points now:  Now I'm getting:

`LoadError: incompatible library version /shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.7.1/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.so`

In Capistrano.

A bit further down, I get:

`LoadError: cannot load such file -- nokogiri/2.3/nokogiri`

Comment: Uh, Nokogiri is a whole different story. I'm not sure what it uses under the hood, but probably some `libxml`. Maybe there it some discrepancy here as well?

Comment: @katafrakt - I just nuked the entire /shared/bundle directory in my app and re-ran Capistrano. I feel like RVM is pretty underdeveloped for this kind of thing... Or maybe Capistrano.  Who knows.

Anyway, if you would like to submit your comment as an answer, I'll give you an upvote and green check :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of error usually means that there is something wrong with PostgreSQL versions installed on your target machine - either the are too old or they are somehow incompatible.